# NSManagedObjectContext deleteObject not working after app kill

Tags: ios, core-data, nsindexset

My app is trying to download json data from the BE and save it to the core data. To keep track of the remaining data content to download, I save them in core data too. When the data is downloaded in batches of say 10, I would remove the downloaded data IDs from the core data object. It works fine when the goes to background. If the app is killed during data download, it resumes when the app becomes active. However after download, I couldn't delete the downloaded data IDs from the NSManagedObjectContext. 
 I have attached the code below:

```
- (void)removeIdListAtIndexesCustomized:(NSIndexSet *)indexes {
       NSMutableOrderedSet *IdListMutable = [self mutableOrderedSetValueForKey:@"IdList"];

      [indexes enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
      [NSManagedObjectContext deleteObject:[IdListMutable objectAtIndex:idx]];//this is where the program stops
      }];
      NSError *error;
      if (![NSManagedObjectContext  save:&error]) {
         NSLog(@"Save failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
      }
 }

-(void)resumeSync{

   SyncData *syncData = [SyncData getSyncData]; //main thread
    NSInvocationOperation  *syncOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(getEvents:) object:syncData];
   [syncQueue addOperation:syncOperation];

}

-(void)getEvents:(SyncData *)syncData{

  //....

  [[DataManager sharedInstance] loadEvents:syncData];
  NSIndexSet *albumIndexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 15)];
  [syncData removeAlbumIdListAtIndexesCustomized:albumIndexSet];
}

DataManager.m

-(void)loadEvents:(SyncData *)data{
   EventRequest *eventRequest = [EventRequest new];
   eventRequest.albumData = postData;
   eventDataOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                            selector:@selector(loadEventRequest:)
                                                              object:eventRequest];
   // Add the operation to the queue and let it to be executed.
   [eventOperationQueue addOperation:eventDataOperation];
   if ([[eventOperationQueue operations] eventDataOperation]) {
      [eventDataOperation waitUntilFinished];
   }
  }
```

Comment: In what way does it fail? Your sample code prints an error message, so what does that message say?

Comment: It stops at deleteObject and doesn't proceed further.

Comment: If `deleteObject:` never returns, it's almost certainly a threading problem.

Comment: this issue is seen only when I kill the app or stop XCode. It must be the same thread pattern that I was using before

Comment: Fine, but what kind of multithreading are you doing?

Comment: I'm using an operationqueue to implement this. Lets say operationqueue X's operation calls a method which runs on operationqueue Y where the Y's operation waitsuntilfinished.

Comment: Add some sample code describing that, because it's probably the source of the problem.

Comment: When the device goes to sleep mode or switch to another app without closing, I don't see this issue.

Comment: Yes I know. Are you going to provide any more detail about your threading or not?

Comment: can you help me on this by more specific what would I need to provide?